# PODIO PHP API, existing contact is not returned

Tags: php, podio

I am trying to check if a contact exist already before creating it.

below is a sample of my code,

```
$contact_fields_index = array("name"=>"Paul Pierre", "mail"=>"paul@barnardmail.net");
$existingContacts = PodioContact::get_for_app( $PODIO_APPID , $contact_fields_index);
```

`$existingContacts` is always empty, even though the contact exists in the workspace.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What happens when you use the general Get Contact operation instead of the one that's scoped down to a specific app? Details: https://developers.podio.com/doc/contacts/get-contacts-22400

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your mail might be not matching, or your name.
Did you try without the attributes parameter? For example:

```
$existingContacts = PodioContact::get_for_app( $PODIO_APPID );
```

That should bring back all contacts and when output the $existingContacts array you can see if the one you are looking for is in there.